# using a var and a string to find a folder

Tags: javascript

to say some space and repetition I'm trying to use a var n to store a common location for a folder but also want to later combine a image name.

example.

```
var n="/me/work/air/image/";
var get_images = ["'+n+'" "1.jpg"",n+ "2.jpg" ]
```

I'm simply just trying to include var n with the string "1.jpg"
so the result would be

```
"/me/work/air/image/1.jpg","/me/work/air/image/2.jpg"
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is. Also: `var get_images = [n + "1.jpg", n + "2.jpg"];` OR if your images are named as such: `var get_images = []; for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) get_images.push(n + i + ".jpg");` now `get_images` will have full paths of images from 1 to 5.

Comment: something wrong with defining your object, should be `var get_images = [n+"1.jpg",n+ "2.jpg" ];` but anyhow we need to know.... where is the question??!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var n= "/me/work/air/image/";
var get_images = [];
for (var i=0; i < 30; i++) {
    get_images.push(n + "" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rMg3M/

Comment: thats like my answer but slower.

Comment: oops didnt see your answer.  I do like the `getImg(i)` function you used, and yours is faster because you only do 10, not 30.  Any reason other than that it would be **significantly** faster?

Comment: it's faster becauseit use while-- & does not use push . setting an array direct with a defined index. significantly? nah not much.

Comment: seems like a question for stackoverflow (lol) but how much faster?

Comment: it also depends in which contest he reuses the images.

Comment: there are many tests made with the while + for loop just search with google.

Comment: im not convinced: http://jsperf.com/the-loops/15

Comment: lol .. jsperf has some serious problems.. especially whithe the while loops... and you can't really test the speed on those type of loops with jsperf.. tests where made using microtime...

Comment: although I suppose that doesnt have to do with push vs []

Comment: i lost the bookmark . but a guy had the luck to test real life while -- loops on alot of browsers.. and while won.. even if the impact is minimal on modern browsers. and another point is the push... executing a function (push) is always slower than setting somethign with given values. it's also possible that the latest chrome is faster doing the for loop..and using push...

Comment: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/01/24/javascript-performance-for-vs-while/ here is one but that is nothing compared to the tests made by the other article.

Comment: tip .. jsperf isn't that good for specific tests.. it works for some stuff.. but you need to pay attention what you put where. if you wanna test the real speed of you function use console.time() or howit's called..

Comment: bitwise operators are faster then math(round,floor,ceil whatever) , shorthand if's are faster than if(){} and while -- is the fastest loop and also the shortest to write.setting a value direct is faster than executing a function to set it.even if it's a native function.

Comment: I agree with some of the comments you are making, but I just cannot find clear cut evidence that a while loop is significantly faster than a for loop.

Comment: no.. it's not significantly faster ... we talk about microseconds. millions of operationsper second.

Comment: but I recognize that that is significant in terms of large data sets, etc. Thanks

Comment: i can't find the benchmarks... but any non jsperfsite will tell u that while wins on all browsers especially old ones.more older the browser isthan bigger is the difference... i remeber you noticed it  on old pentium 1's on some big functions.

Comment: look what jsperf does in this while loop...  http://jsperf.com/while-vs-loopssss ... it's impossible that the while loop is 10 times slower .. thats a typical error of jsperf...

Answer (score 0):

this while loop is prolly the fastest one...  length is the number of images ..

```
var path='/me/work/air/image/',length=10,array=[];
while(length--){
 array[length]=path+length+'.jpg'
}
array.shift() // if you start from 1
```

or just create a function where i is the number of the image

```
function getImg(i){
 return '/me/work/air/image/'+i+'.jpg'
}
```

use

```
var image1=getImg(1);
```

or

```
'<img src="'+getImg(1)+'">'
```

it also all depends inwhich contest you wanna reuse the image later and how often

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var n= "/me/work/air/image/";
var get_images = {
     first: n + "1.jpg", 
     second: n+ "2.jpg" 
    };
```

Now you can use get_Images["first"] or get_Images.first to get the data of each properties of JSON object.

Comment: how does this work if I have like 30 .jpg's not 2